# CSS nth-child circular styling

Tags: css, css-selectors, sequence

I have a sequence of 6 colors:

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Cyan
- Magenta
- Yellow

Whereas element 1 is red.

Element 2 is green… etc.

The list can have an unlimited number of items, and the color sequence should be kept.

The easiest way would be to use nth-child(n%6), but we know that there's no module operator for nth-child.

The sequence:

- nth-child(n): Red
- nth-child(2n): Green
- nth-child(3n): Blue
- nth-child(4n): Cyan
- …

Wouldn't work, since the 8th element would be Cyan, but it should instead be Green.

An offset wouldn't work either as it would work only for the first occurrences.

Can this problem be solved?

Comment: Based on your sequence why is the first element yellow instead of red?

Comment: Is _Whereas element 1 is yellow._ a typo and should be _Whereas element 1 is red._?

Comment: The "yellow" was a mistake that I did while formulating the question (my real application is quiet different). Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this

- `nth-child(6n-5)` for every 6:th, start at 6-5 = 1
- `nth-child(6n-4)` for every 6:th, start at 6-4 = 2
- etc.
- `nth-child(6n-0)` for every 6:th, start at 6-0 = 6    (can be written as `nth-child(6n)`)

*or like this (updated and maybe more appropriate in this case)*

- *`nth-child(6n+1)` for every 6:th, start at 1*
- *`nth-child(6n+2)` for every 6:th, start at 2*
- *etc.*
- *`nth-child(6n+6)` for every 6:th, start at 6   (can be written as `nth-child(6n)`)*

```css
/* left div's */
.left div:nth-child(6n-5) {
  background: red;
}
.left div:nth-child(6n-4) {
  background: green;
}
.left div:nth-child(6n-3) {
  background: blue;
}
.left div:nth-child(6n-2) {
  background: cyan;
}
.left div:nth-child(6n-1) {
  background: magenta;
}
.left div:nth-child(6n) {
  background: yellow;  
}
/* right div's */
.right div:nth-child(6n+1) {
  background: red;
}
.right div:nth-child(6n+2) {
  background: green;
}
.right div:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: blue;
}
.right div:nth-child(6n+4) {
  background: cyan;
}
.right div:nth-child(6n+5) {
  background: magenta;
}
.right div:nth-child(6n) {
  background: yellow;  
}

/* for this demo only */
div div:nth-child(6n) + div {
  margin-top: 15px;  
}
.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>  
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: But then first element is not yellow (that seems to be an OP requirement... that I don't really understand)

Comment: @vals I think that is a typo in the question, and if not, I will update my answer ... I guess we all wait for a response on _j08691_'s comment

Comment: I see what you did, basically:

- (6n) = [0, 6, 12, 18, …] % 6 = 0.
- (6n - 5) = [1, 7, 13, 19, …] % 6 = 1
- …
- (6n - 1) = [-1, 5, 11, 17, …] % 6 = 5.

You first decided that it should pick only N that are a multiple of the desired module, and then to it subtract each of the possible [module] results.

Comment: Are there any ways to do like `3n-n` in nth-child?

Comment: @l3lue It might. What do you mean the 2nd `n` is meant to represent?

Comment: @LGSon I was trying to get the even numbers with that but I've figured out getting even numbers could deal with just like this `2n`

Comment: @l3lue Ok, or use `even`, e.g. `nth-child(even)`

Comment: @LGSon :O was that working too? didn't know about that

Comment: @l3lue Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 1):

> but we know that there's no module operator for nth-child.

What makes you think `:nth-child` has no modulus syntax?

If you want `:nth-child(x)`, where `x ∈ ℤa` and `a ∈ ℕ`, then the syntax is

```css
:nth-child(an + b)
```

where `b ∈ ℤ` is any representative of `x` such that `b < a`.

As you can see in LGSon's answer, usually `b` is chosen in one of these sets

- `{0, 1, …, a-1}`
- `{-a, -a+1, …, -1}`
- `{-a+1, …, -1, 0}`

Note: In this answer, `ℤa` means `ℤ⧸aℤ`, that is, the [integers modulo `a`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n).

Comment: Good answer ... but may be the OP won't understand the mathematical notation